# What is WCF readerQuotas and maxArrayLength?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, readerquotas

Can anyone explain WCF `<readerQuotas>` to me? Specifically `maxArrayLength`.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `maxArrayLength`
>
> A positive integer that specifies the maximum allowed
>   array length of data being received by Windows Communication
>   Foundation (WCF) from a client. The default is 16384.

What is it? Bytes?

What happens if I don't set it?

What happens if I set it and the message returned goes beyond the specified length?

Isn't it possible that the message may exceed even the maximum value set? Then what's the point of setting this value?

Comment: questions are good, but in one question u have asked 5 to 6 questions

Comment: @Freelancer Well they are all related so didn't really see the point asking them separately... :)

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to simplify this as best as possible:

- `maxArrayLength` = how many elements can your array or list hold.
- `maxBytesPerRead` = max bytes for the entire message
- `maxDepth` = how many levels down can an array go? For example a class can have an arrays, and each element has an array, and each element of that has an array.....
- `maxStringContentLength` = max XML content length